# How can i call C++ Code from JavaScripts with the NPAPI

Tags: c++, firefox, npapi, browser-plugin

I saw that one can call the c++ code from JavaScript like this: [Calling C++ Code from DHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/dx3d2ftc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

But it is for IE,i use NPAPI to implement a plugin for firefox,and i want to call the method which is defined in c++ code via html file,how can i get it?

Comment: As far as I understand the article, it is only applicable when using an IE control *within your application*. Your case is completely different – you have to have a look at the documentation of the Firefox interface for plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org).  That's by far the easiest tool for building a plugin to do what you want.  Barring that, there are [tutorials](http://npapi.com/tutorial1) [you](http://npapi.com/tutorial2) [can](http://npapi.com/tutorial3) [read](http://npapi.com/tutorial4) to learn about building an NPAPI plugin from scratch, though it's a bit of a pain.

There is also [nixysa](https://code.google.com/p/nixysa/), though i've never used it myself.

However you do it (and I strongly recommend FireBreath, since once you have the tools needed to use it you can get a new plugin up in literally 30 minutes or less) you need to expose a scriptable object to the page. If you're using NPAPI directly that means providing an NPObject (discussed in [tutorial part 3](http://npapi.com/tutorial3)) that the page will be able to access.

Comment: Thank for your answer again,taxilian.you exsit everywhere.In my eyes,the firebreath is more pain than npapi.For ,I have no idear on how to get the handle of the window,how to create a window with the method like "CreateWindowEx",and what's more,how to get the interaction between html and cpp file.er,the tutials about firebreath is hard to find,i'm confused now.

Comment: So ask specific questions about how to do those things; however, you'll find most of the answers to those questions on the Getting Started sections of the website. Next check the tips and tricks section, look at http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/firebreath-tips-drawing-on-windows/, and if all else fails you can always try the google group or http://npapi.com/chat, both of which I monitor as best I can.  I wrote FireBreath, btw.